# bpy.ops.object.lamp_add not found

Tags: python

I am trying to run some old script example which states

```
# Add a sun lamp above the grid.
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='SUN', radius=1.0, location=(0.0, 0.0, extents * 0.667))
```

and it says

```
AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.lamp_add" error, could not be found
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

How to do the same in modern Blender `2.91.0`? How to find replacements for old constructs systematically?

Comment: It's `light_add` now.

Comment: Recommend familiarizing yourself with blenders python console, making use of autocomplete, in this instance typing in `bpy.ops.object.l<TAB>` (where <TAB> is the tab key for autocomplete) will reveal the answer IMO quicker than asking here.

Comment: @batFINGER how would I know first letter `l`? without knowing `l` this archaic "autocomplete" shows very long list.

Comment: even, heaven forbid you read the _"very long list"_   **light_add**  kinda stands out as the one.

Comment: no, no, heaven doesn't forbid me reading long lists, it has no time for it, since it is busy forbidding to make normal intellisence in `Blender` :D

Answer (score 2):

Recommended way is to use low level API calls anyway. Create a new *data block*, create an *object*, *link* the data block and *add the object to the collection in context*:

```
import bpy

# Create light datablock
light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="my-light-data", type='POINT')
light_data.energy = 100

# Create new object, pass the light data 
light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="my-light", object_data=light_data)

# Link object to collection in context
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)

# Change light position
light_object.location = (0, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Ya, but how would I know that `POINT` is the same as `SUN` and that `energy` should be `100`?

Comment: @Dims, read the docs https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLights.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLights.new